# Open frameworks save frame returning black images

Tags: rendering, openframeworks, movie

I'm attempting to save individual frames of an open frameworks sketch to then compile into a movie, I'm using the command "ofSaveFrame()" in the draw section of the code, but for some reason all the resulting .png's are black. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Solved the issue on the openframeworks forum https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/saveframe/25124/5

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to locate the two files in your project ofGLRenderer.cpp and ofGLProgrammableRenderer.cpp

I changed both ofGLRenderer::saveScreen() and ofGLProgrammableRenderer::saveScreen() to look like this

```
#ifndef TARGET_OPENGLES

    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
    pixels.allocate(w, h, OF_PIXELS_RGB);

    if(isVFlipped()){
       y = sh - y;
       y -= h; // top, bottom issues
    }
    glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.getData()); // read the memory....

#else
```